# Add plugin metadata on woocommerce product creation using the REST API

Tags: php, rest, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, woocommerce-rest-api

Looking at the [Woocommerce documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product), very little is said about adding custom metadata. Apart from some key value addition that doesn't seem to relate to plugins.

I have a plugin called "gravity forms" which also has its own extensive [REST Api](https://docs.gravityforms.com/web-api-v2/), however I cannot work out how to automatically assign a particular gravity form to a product when I create it. (their rest api seems to deal primarily with managing the forms, not assigning them to products)

When I pull a specific product with an assigned gravity form it has this custom metadata:

`"metadata": [...,{
    {"id"=>24866,
    "key"=>"_gravity_form_data",
    "value"=>
     {"id"=>"6",
      "display_title"=>false,
      "display_description"=>false,
      "disable_woocommerce_price"=>"no",
      "price_before"=>"",
      "price_after"=>"",
      "disable_calculations"=>"no",
      "disable_label_subtotal"=>"no",
      "disable_label_options"=>"no",
      "disable_label_total"=>"no",
      "disable_anchor"=>"no",
      "label_subtotal"=>"Subtotal",
      "label_options"=>"Options",
      "label_total"=>"Total",
      "use_ajax"=>"no"}}]`

however, when I try and autoamtically assign that metadata on product for example, as `metadata: [{_gravity_form_data: { id: 6...}}]`, it doesn't automatically assign the gravity form to the product.

Question 1) what ways are there to automatically assign the gravity form to a product?

Question 2) if it can be done after product creation, how do I take the product id and assign that gravity form to it? Do i have to use a post creation hook - I'd prefer to stick primarily to REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the [WC API Custom Metadata Plugin](https://github.com/judgej/wc-api-custom-meta), which meant I could pull a previously modified product with the new gravity form, but this will work for any metadata object. I could then edit my POST request with:

`meta_data: [
            {
              key: "_gravity_form_data",
              value:  {
                id: "6",
                display_title: false,
                display_description: false,
                disable_woocommerce_price: "no",
                price_before: "",
                price_after: "",
                disable_calculations: "no",
                disable_label_subtotal: "no",
                disable_label_options: "no",
                disable_label_total: "no",
                disable_anchor: "no",
                label_subtotal: "Subtotal",
                label_options: "Options",
                label_total: "Total",
                use_ajax: "no"
              }
            }
          ]`

And it will automatically give it an ID and auto assign the gravity form to the product!